# One type with multiple use cases - one table or two?

Tags: rdbms

I'm making a website which aims to match sellers and buyers. Users can offer items to sell, or request items to purchase, and the website will try to connect prospective sellers and buyers of similar items.

I will be using SQL to store information about each item (user, color, size, brand, type, model-number, quantity, etc).

The question is, should I make one table for the items, or should I have two tables, one for offered items and one for requested items?

On the one hand, nearly all the properties are the same. On the other hand, I'll rarely query the whole table at once; usually I'll want to search for just offered items or just requested items.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to normalize this is to introduce 3 tables; `users`, `items` and `trades` that have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE items(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    color VARCHAR(8),
    size VARCHAR(8),
    brand VARCHAR(8),
    type VARCHAR(8)
);

CREATE TABLE trades(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    trade ENUM('buy', 'sell'),
    user_id INT REFERENCES users (id),
    item_id INT REFERENCES items (id)
);
```

So if I want to match up a buyer of a specific item with a seller of the same item, I can do a simple joins of the `trades` table. (Additional joins can be included to retrieve information of the buyer, seller and item.)

Live demo on [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00a677/8). The result shows that:

1. Alex wants to buy a small, black ABC hoodie. John has one for sale.
2. Alex wants to buy a small, white EFG shorts. Jane has one for sale.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two tables, one table will be "users" (with single user id) and the other table of "items" in which you have a field of the user id, and the other is for item type (it is for sell or request) is another field of the table where you store the information of the item.